# Can we use flutter with Jetson Nano?

Tags: user-interface, flutter, nvidia-jetson-nano

I have an object detection tensorflow model running on Jetson Nano. I want to create a flutter App which controls this program on jetson Nano. Is it possible ? How can i do that? I mean, can we interface flutter with jetson nano?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Jetson Nano but as I understand :

1. Jetson Nano provides the development kit
2. One can write Python program to run on the Jetson Nano.

If above is true, you can make these two guys talk by means of REST APIs.

The program on Jetson Nano exposes certain features and/or by means of APIs. And the Flutter (read: Dart) programs consumes the APIs. This set-up is just like any other set-up. For example, if the Flutter app wants to write something in the server database then we expose the read/write operations by means of APIs and call those APIs from the Flutter app.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to convert your TensorFlow Model to .tflite format and use the model inside your flutter APP.

It would be hard to control your Jetson Nano with Flutter, but you can use some SSH APP on your phone and connect to your Jetson Nano to do your operation.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can. I succeeded in building on jetson.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).